# SEO-friendly URLs are being corrupted after update

Tags: url, joomla-4.x, sef, seo

I have built a directory website and started to add some content. I have created the standard pages (contact us, privacy, etc.) and added businesses. I would like SEO-friendly URLs, so I set:

- Search Engine Friendly URLs
- URL Rewriting - YES
- Suffix - No

However, Joomla somehow rewrites my aliases and changes them.

For example: `mywebsite/bar-and-dinner` is displayed as `mywebsite/bar-din-r`.

I contacted the support of the plugin I use and they told me that I must have had some filters on Joomla that creates such a problem. I tried to purge the cache on the website & server, but it's still the same. I just updated to Joomla 4.0.

What can I do to prevent the corruption of my SEO-friendly URLs?

Comment: Welcome to JSE and thank you for asking your question, @33money.  Please take our [tour] while you wait for feedback/support.  Please avoid adding irrelevant text to posts such as "Good afternoon", "Thanks for reading", "I'm new", "I need help", "I would be really appreciative", "Thanks in advance", "My name is 33money", etc.  You haven't done all of these things, but this is an opportunity to inform readers that we only want the relevant bits in the question body.  This makes a better, faster research experience for future readers (especially ones with visual impairments).

Comment: What is the plugin you mention that you use? If you disable the plugin are the URL's displayed as you expect?

Comment: Hi, I am using JB plugin. However, I disabled it but the problem is still there. I've noticed the URL is rewritten when I have words with double "n", "a" and "e" (in my non English language).